# Question on exercise of ideal of a point

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-verification

The question was to find the ideal of a point $(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ in $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y]$ and its conjugates in $\mathbb{C}^2$. Is is correct to say that the ideal of a point is $\{Q(x,y)(x^2-2)(y^2-3)|Q(x,y)\in \mathbb{Q}[X,Y]\}$ as $x^2-2$ and $y^2-3$ are irreducible over $\mathbb Q$? And is the conjugate just $\{Q(x,y)(x^2+2)(y^2+3)|Q(x,y)\in \mathbb{Q}[X,Y]\}$ as $i^2=-1$?

Comment: (1) I don't think $i$ really enters into it. What is smallest field Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$ that contains $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$? What does that group do to the point? (2) At the very least I think $x^2 - 2$ should be in this ideal and I don't see it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ideal of $(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ is $I=\langle X^2-2,Y^2-3\rangle \subset  \mathbb{Q}[X,Y]$ .
Note carefully that the zero set $V_\mathbb C(I)\subset \mathbb C^2$ of the ideal $I$ in   $\mathbb C^2$ consists of the $4$ 
 conjugates $(\pm \sqrt{2},\pm\sqrt{3})$ of $(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ and  that $V_\mathbb C(I)$ is the closure in $\mathbb C^2$ of the singleton $ \{(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})\}$ (in the $\mathbb{Q}-\mathbb C$ topology) .

This  rather naïve mixing of the fields $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb C$  finds  a more satisfactory context in the theory of schemes, where you can  very naturally speak of the $\mathbb C$-points of  a $\mathbb Q$-scheme.